# Updating a jQuery function on the fly

Tags: jquery

I have this code below that filters my array for only items that have type **For Sale**. *classifieldData* being the array:

```
var found_classifields = $.grep(classifieldData, function(v) {
    return v.type === 'For Sale';
});
```

And at some point when the user selects some things on the page I will need to redo that functions return by adding **&& v.price >= 30** like so:

```
var found_classifields = $.grep(classifieldData, function(v) {
    return v.type === 'For Sale' && v.price >= 30;
});
```

How do I go about calling that function again with the new parameter **v.type === 'For Sale' && v.price >= 30**

Comment: _"And at some point when the user selects some things on the page"_ How is this determined ?

Comment: @guest271314 Select boxes with values.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you mean by " some point" I assume it is some event or a certain condition that activates the second form of comparison. So just check for it before returning results.

```
If(somePointArrived){
     Return Condition1 && theGreaterThan30thing;
  }   
else {return Condition1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable that says whether to check the price, and combine that into the test.

```
var check_price = false;

function get_classifields() {
    var found_classifields = $.grep(classifieldData, function(v) {
        return v.type === 'For Sale' && (!check_price || v.price >= 30);
    });
    return found_classifields;
}
```

When the user selects something on the page, do

```
check_price = true;
```

to tell the function that it should include this test.

Comment: Half of that I get. But the part I do not is how I go about calling the function again? I currently just have that function in the onDomReady state. Do I just call **$.grep** again?

Comment: I assumed this was just part of a named function. So you just call the function by name whenever you need to.

Comment: Sorry still don't follow. Mind putting an example in your answer?

Comment: I added the function definition.

Comment: And i gather that if I need to add a 3rd addition than I just make another true/false variable?

Comment: Yes, although if you do this too much the expression will become very confusing. You may want to consider some more organized approach if there are many conditions.

Comment: Like **function get_classifields(check_price, check_color)**?